# Does the wave function of localized s-orbitals radius reduce under extreme solid-state pressures prior to degeneracy?

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, white-dwarfs

Under extreme conditions not found in nature, say **low** temperature solids that are under extreme pressures*  prior to collapse into degenerate matter states, does a localized s-orbital radius reduce from its unpressurized solid state?

By "localized s-orbital" I mean, for example, the $1s^2$ orbital of elements with atomic number beyond Helium.

* found in nature only in **high** temperature conditions such as stellar interiors